# How do you scale the carousel container size in Angular-UI-Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

Right now the carousel container falls outside the image.

[image]

I want the carousel container to have the same width as the image as shown in the example on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="offer-detail-image-div">
  <uib-carousel active="0" interval="2000" no-wrap="false" no-pause="false">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
      <img class="offer-detail-image" ng-src= {{slide.image}}
    </uib-slide>
  </uib-carousel>
</div>
```

And the accompanying classes:

```
.offer-detail-image {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 70%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: auto;
  float: none;
}



 .offer-detail-image-div {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the css like this u have to give 100% width and also in your css u have mention max-width 80%.

```css
.offer-detail-image {
      display: block;
      overflow: visible;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      margin-left: auto;
      float: none;
    }
```

Comment: good madam cz i am madam  . and no need madame i am gayathri . happy coding @rashadb